# No antializing in chrome with font-face (in some places)

Tags: css, macos, font-face

The project I'm working on is secret, so I can't show you, but I will do my best to explain it.

So the deal is that I'm using a font through @font-face (generated via fontsquirell). The font is being used as headlines and in the main menu which is kinda big and Arial is used for copy.

The problem is that in Chrome and IE (not Fx or Opera), the text in the menu looks ugly, it's not smooth. The rest of the page works as supposed, only in the menu this happens. But when I hover a link in the menu, it transforms into a beautiful text (what probably happens is some kind of reflow or something).

I have two files (that's important in this case):
screen_typography.css
screen_layout.css

I got a minifier thingy going on so in the end it's only one css file that the browser load. In the typography file im importing the font and sets it to the headlines. In layout css I'm setting the font for the menu. The font is set to the -tag which is inside the li.

**In the moment of writing I'm seeing that this only occurs in Mac OSX, not on Windows (haven't tested it on Linux).**

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in IE – I found that setting position:relative on the text fixed it. Not sure why though!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Didn't do it though, but I came up with a solution! :D

Comment: What was the solution? You can answer your own question and accept the answer if you think it will help other people.

Comment: Yes man. Just have to wait until tomorrow :) Maybe someone comes with a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by setting the navs parent to position absolute and the nav itself. Then I gave the nav a z-index value of -1, to hide behind its parent but still being interactive since the parent doesn't have a background. That way, the parent acts like a shield to protect its child from getting dirty :D